# SQL Self join table, defaulting to null and removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL model (MySQL v8.0.20) that describes a physical card with 1 or 2 faces. Because card faces can appear on multiple physical cards, I've modeled this as a many-many relationship using the join table `cardFaces`.

I'm now trying to get a list of distinct front facing cards. That is if a card has only 1 face, it would be represented once, if it has 2 faces, it would be represented twice (once for each side front facing).

### Input

The join table currently looks like this (simplified for question):

```
SELECT * FROM cardFaces;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | cardId | faceId |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      A |      1 |
|  2 |      B |      2 |
|  3 |      B |      3 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

### Expected Output

The result I'm expecting to achieve is this:

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| cardId | frontFaceId | backFaceId |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      A |           1 |       NULL |
|      B |           2 |          3 |
|      B |           3 |          2 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

### Current Output

I've only gotten so far as self-joining and removing duplicates, but I can't figure out how to introduce `NULL` as the `backFaceId` for cards with only 1 face.

```
SELECT frontFace.cardId, frontFace.faceId frontFaceId, backFace.faceId backFaceId
FROM cardFaces frontFace
LEFT JOIN cardFaces backFace
ON frontFace.cardId = backFace.cardId
WHERE backFace.id != frontFace.id;

+--------+-------------+------------+
| cardId | frontFaceId | backFaceId |
+--------+-------------+------------+
|      B |           2 |          3 |
|      B |           3 |          2 |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Where conditions on outer joined table's column turns outer join to inner join if you do not take care of nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT frontFace.cardId, frontFace.faceId frontFaceId, backFace.faceId backFaceId
FROM cardFaces frontFace LEFT JOIN
     cardFaces backFace
     ON frontFace.cardId = backFace.cardId AND
        backFace.id <> frontFace.id;
```

`NULL`s fail almost all comparisons, including `<>`, turning the outer join into an inner join.